# Microsoft HPC SetCreds results in the server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: client, jobs, credentials, hpc

I am trying to set credentials (for running a job) using
cluscfg setcreds /scheduler:scheduler1 /user:domain2\user1 /password:pass

I get "The server has rejected the client credentials"

The client machine is in domain1.

Question:
1. Is this related to crossing the domain?
2. Is this related to some attribute on the account? That the account is not sufficiently 
privileged to be able to run an HPC job?

Answer (score 1):

1. Which domain is the scheduler in? If the scheduler is in domain2 and there's no trust relationship between domain1 and domain2 you may have credential problems. Can you use the Job Manager or Cluster Manager UI to look at scheduler1 from your client machine?
2. DOMAIN2\user1 needs to be configured as a cluster user (or administrator) on scheduler1. You can do that by manually adding DOMAIN2\user1 in the cluster configuration UI, or you can add some group which contains DOMAIN2\user1 (such as DOMAIN2\DOMAIN USERS).
3. Sorry for the late response; I don't check StackOverflow as often as I should :-\